Application is launching using FlaUI but it then goes into wait state
var application = Application.Launch(@"myapplication.exe");
                var mainWindow = application.GetMainWindow(new UIA3Automation());
                //ConditionFactory cf = new ConditionFactory(new UIA3PropertyLibrary());
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
                mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf=>cf.ByAutomationId("QuickLinksTopMenu")).AsButton().Click();

After I launch a application, the application opens and goes into wait state and doesn't perform any click operations or input operations neither it fails the unit test nor passes it, it's keep running how to resolve it.
I have added Thread.Sleep() method also to insure that it first gets the main window and then the operation start executing but nothing happens.

You can use a more reliable approach to implement the waiting process, instead of Thread.Sleep():
var quickLinksButton = Retry.WhileNull(
    () => mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(conditionFactory.ByAutomationId("QuickLinksTopMenu")),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

if (quickLinksButton != null)
{
    var invokePattern = quickLinksButton.Patterns.Invoke.Pattern;
    if (invokePattern != null)
    {
        invokePattern.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfound");
}

Retry method:
public static class Retry
{
    public static T WhileNull<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan retryInterval) where T : class
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        T result = null;

        while ((DateTime.Now - startTime) < timeout)
        {
            result = action();
            if (result != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
        }

        return result;
    }
}


It is not recognizing Retry keyword, how to resolve this?

The codes have been edited. @ShantanuKumarKar

This will infinitely loop through this. If you look at the method, you will see it has a secondary argument that gives it a time limit. Try with that first to see if that helps.
var mainWindow = application.GetMainWindow(new UIA3Automation());

